# Is it possible to programatically detect when speakers are powered on/off?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

I was wondering, does Windows receive any signal when speakers are powered on? Specifically when I turn the knob on them clockwise to turn them on.

The reason I am asking is because I was thinking about writing a script that would switch my output sound device between speakers & headphones automatically when I turn the speakers on/off, but not sure if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely unless they're USB or Bluetooth - something with a 2-way communication protocol.

Regular speakers or amp & speakers are just a 'dumb' connection. If you send signal to them there is no feedback as to whether it arrived or was treated in any way. Mini-jack sockets can have switches built-in so the computer can recognise if a plug is inserted, but still it isn't truly aware of what's going on at the other end of the cable.

I have a semi-pro USB interface with actual physical moving VU-meters -  display 'needles'. If my speakers are off, these can be dancing round as though there was noise going on… but silently. The unit has no way of knowing the signal's not going anywhere.

[image]